# missing in function applied to pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, missing-data

I'm trying to apply a function to my 'age' and 'area' columns in order to get the results that I show in the column 'wanted'.

Unfortunately this funtion gives me errors. I know that there are other methods in Pandas, like iloc, but I would like to understand this particular situation.

```
raw_data = {'age': [-1, np.nan, 10, 300, 20],'area': ['N','S','W',np.nan,np.nan],
    'wanted': ['A',np.nan,'A',np.nan,np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['age','area','wanted'])
df

def my_funct(df) :

    if df["age"].isnull() :
        return np.nan 
    elif df["area"].notnull():
        return 'A'
    else:
        return np.nan

df["target"] = df.apply(lambda df:my_funct(df) ,axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the problem is when you pass a row to your function, by referencing df['age'], it gives you a float, which doesn't have a method called isnull(). To check if a float is null, you can use the pd.isna function. Similar case for notna().

```
def my_funct(df) :

    if pd.isna(df["age"]) :
        return np.nan 
    elif pd.notna(df["area"]):
        return 'A'
    else:
        return np.nan

df["target"] = df.apply(lambda x: my_funct(x) ,axis = 1)
```